# password request window wont center on screen :(

Tags: javascript, passwords, center

I've tried using width, height, top and left parameters in the window.open parenthesis but no matter what I do the Javascript popup notification still stays in the top left corner.

Can anyone assist please?

```
function password() {
var testV = 1;
var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your Password','Enter your password here');
while (testV < 3) {
if (!pass1) 
history.go(0);
if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "test") {
/*alert('You Are Successful, Click To Continue!'); */
var targetWin = window.open('');
break;
} 
testV+=1;
var pass1 = 
prompt('Access Denied - Your Password Is Incorrect, Please Try Again.','Enter your     
password here');
}
if (pass1.toLowerCase()!="password" & testV ==3) 
history.go(0);
return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to center the targetWin try doing something like this:

`Assuming your targetWindow size is 485 by 700.`

```
function openWindow(meh)
{
    var x = screen.width/2 - 700/2;
    var y = screen.height/2 - 450/2;
    window.open(meh.href, 'sharegplus','height=485,width=700,left='+x+',top='+y);
}

var targetWin = openWindow(<url>);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can. Like the alert, the prompt is wired into the browser along with it's position and behavior. If you want an 'alert' or 'prompt' that you can control, you will have to create a java script popup using html and css directly with your java script. Might i suggest a jquery popup form like this:
http://www.formmail-maker.com/var/demo/jquery-popup-form/popup-contact-form.html

Answer (score 0):

The "top" parameter is for IE only so it won't effect any other browser you may be targeting. For Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera you will have to find another way to align it vertically. Your best bet will be to use Java, HTML, and CSS together to get it to look the way you want it to.

jquery is a good option. just remember that if someone doesn't have java script enabled on their computer/device, it wont work properly either. for the most responsive design, you may have to program in multiple ways of doing the same thing. You can try using jquery and the code Jose posted together to see how it works in multiple browsers.

Comment: doesn't look like there are any solutions, many thanks for your comments.  At least the function is working.

Comment: @StephenLawrence Fair enough, but were any of us helpful in some way ;)?